# How to change the lamp strength using python scripting, for cycles renderer?

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, light

I have inserted a HEMI type lamp in the scene using python scripting. Now I also want to change the strength of that lamp via python. I am using cycles to render my scene.

I am stuck here, thanks for helping.

Comment: Did you try change the setting, then look in the info-space? - it gives the command used to change the setting.

Comment: This question is unnecessarily very specific, I've asked a more general question which covers the same field.

Comment: you can get it by hovering you mouse over the property you can to change, as along as tooltips are enabled. You will see the Python command for it.